# Data-Visualisation and the Users Expectations

Tags: interaction-design, user-expectation, info-visualisation, graphs

I am currently working on an app to do with pensions. I have a graphical representation showing how much the user will have at their chosen retirement age; these are based on defined contributions and benefits ect.

What are the rules if any, around making graphs and or other graphical visualisations interactive; in so far that the user can physically alter the data directly? Should the user still be given levers and switches to make the same amends?

Cheers

I have attached an image to illustrate further.
[image]

Comment: What you describe sounds like a slider calculator (see picture) to me. What kind of data visualisation is going to be present there? https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Q4duK104_oxGujRvmj3RTmsbtGyKqvb5qBo9tRVKbID2uHsjik63LGGwPq4fkcLvOEyS5GwlKA=s640-h400-e365

Comment: I have added an image to help demonstrate what I was doing. My original question was directly related to the slider at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description above, I wouldn't necessarily allow them to enter their own data as that could get very messy with human error. Instead why not given them controls( kind of like a form) that allow them to customise the parameters of the data that is presented to them.

Comment: Thank you, that's great! You confirmed what I thought. 

The graphical requirement came from an avid Tablet user. 
I assume if I was to use a series of controls that I should do the same across all devices?

Comment: Yep keep the options available consistant across all platforms, just make sure it doesn't contradict native design features.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, it is common to use form controls to output the desired graphical result e.g input fields, slider etc. Nowadays the trend seems to move towards direct manipulation on the graph itself. Meaning you interact with the graph to achieve your results. One good example is [acorns](http://www.acorns.com). Scroll down to see their smart portfolios.

If your data are predetermined and the level of granularity is not important, then you might to consider this as an option.